# Where is 'FixedUpdate' in Unity DOTS (ECS)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics-engine, unity-dots

I am starting to find my way into using the DOTS (Data Oriented Technology Stack) method of making objects.

There are several samples all over, Youtube videos and also samples directly from Unity, such as the github repo 'EntityComponentSystemSamples'.

In all of these, I stumble across 'OnUpdate', but never 'OnFixedUpdate'.

Normally, Unity GameObjects would have both, one for each graphics frame update (`OnUpdate`), and one for each physics movement update (`OnFixedUpdate`).

When trying to create behavior that uses Rigidbody.AddForce(), it was always important to use FixedUpdate().

Has this concept been removed in DOTS? How do I add scripted, varying forces to a PhysicsBody in DOTS ?

Currently, I am adding my `force*deltatime` to the `Unity.Physics.PhysicsVelocity` in the update.

Comment: Dots doesn’t have a fixed update. But you can make physics a dependency so your job runs after the physics has

Comment: There is [UnityPhysics for DOTS](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.physics@0.3/manual/index.html) or [Havok Physics for Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.havok.physics@0.2/manual/index.html) as alternative, both via the PackageManager. See [Unity and Havok Physics for DOTS-based projects](https://unity.com/unity/physics#havok-physics) for more information

Comment: Actually, I am not looking into Havok engine right now. I know it is there. I also know about the dependencies. But my question was if the distinction between the update-functions for per-frame and per-phys-tick was lifted or maybe the per-phys-tick is just no longer available for scripting. With either physics engine. From @BugFinder 's answer I should assume that the per-tick is just not available anymore.

Comment: But you could easily make a "per tick" type event for yourself

Comment: You can use `Time.fixedDeltatime` if you're looking for an example there are some ECS samples provided by Unity Technologies. [Here an example with `fixedDeltaTime` in a system](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/EntityComponentSystemSamples/blob/master/UnityPhysicsSamples/Assets/Demos/6.%20Use%20Cases/PlanetGravity/Scripts/PlanetGravityAuthoring.cs).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Every system can belong to a single **System Group** only. You specify this with attributes.

Attribute `[UpdateInGroup(typeof(SimulationSystemGroup))]` makes your `OnUpdate` being called as general game/simulation updates. This is a default group for systems.

Attribute `[UpdateInGroup(typeof(FixedStepSimulationSystemGroup))]` makes your `OnUpdate` being called in fixed simulation intervals (i.e.: **FixedUpdate**).

> Note: This^ correction is taken from @thelebaron answer. Give him an upvote please.

Attribute `[UpdateInGroup(typeof(PresentationSystemGroup))]` makes your `OnUpdate` being called in rendering context; before frames are drawn (i.e: **Update**)

---

```cs
[UpdateInGroup( typeof(SimulationSystemGroup) )]
public class SomeKindOfSimulationSystem : SystemBase
{
    protected override void OnUpdate ()
    {
        /* simulation update */
    }
}
```

```cs
[UpdateInGroup( typeof(PresentationSystemGroup) )]
public class SomeKindOfRenderingSystem : SystemBase
{
    protected override void OnUpdate ()
    {
        /* rendering update */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I cant add a comment due to rep but to follow up Andrew Lukasik's answer, there is now a FixedStepSimulationSystemGroup which you can update your systems in(and is where the Physics systems update inside of).

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please use answer section only for actual answering. Add the comment once you have enough reputation.

Comment: Thanks for the hint I'll look for it.